# Change publish date from meta date when publish post

Tags: wordpress, post

When the post is publish, I want the publish date as the same as the date in the meta data, imic_sermon_date.

Here's my code.  The problem is that it get stuck when publishing a post.

```
function update_sermon_date ($post_id) {
    //automatically change publish date to sermon date when publish/save a postfunction update_sermon_date ($post_id) {
    $sermon_date = get_post_meta($post_id, 'imic_sermon_date', true);
    $mypost = array (
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_date' => $sermon_date);
    wp_update_post( $mypost );
    }

    add_action ('save_post', 'update_sermon_date');
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: the update needs to be inside the callback function update_sermon_date

Comment: @VidyaL - thanks.  I forgot to paste that line of code.

Comment: You said you get stuck when publishing a post, so the post is new one so how will be you get the post meta with the new id?

Comment: Hi @VidyaL , that's the reason why i am asking this. I don't know what i don't know.  If you have any suggestion on how to make this code, I will be thankful :)

Comment: is it updating while saving an existing post?

Comment: @VidyaL - I like to update the date either save from an existing post or create a new post.  The idea is that whenever this post is publish (new or existing), the function will copy the date from imic_sermon_date and overwrite the publish post date.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121696/discussion-between-vidya-l-and-bigreddog).

Answer (score 0):

After searching online, I've fixed my code.

The code basically will only update when the post is edited.  I added remove_action and add_action in order to prevent the code from running an endless loop.

```
****//automatically change publish date to sermon date when publish/save a post
function update_sermon_date () {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;


    if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) )
        return;

    $sermon_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'imic_sermon_date', true); 
    $mypost = array (
        'ID' => get_the_ID(),
        'post_title' => $sermon_date,
        'post_date' => $sermon_date,
        'post_date_gmt' => $sermon_date);

    if ( ! (wp_is_post_revision($post_id) || wp_is_post_autosave ( $post_id) ) ) {
        remove_action('edit_post','update_sermon_date');
        wp_update_post( $mypost );
    add_action ('edit_post', 'update_sermon_date');
    }
}

add_action ('edit_post', 'update_sermon_date');****
```